Alignment of items inside of HeaderTemplate of RadzenPanel
I've specified a custom header-template for a RadzenPanel-component. I want some items to align on the left side and other one on the right side of that panel header.
I found an similiar question here (https://forum.radzen.com/t/how-to-have-a-header-with-some-content-aligned-left-and-some-aligned-right/16284) but the solution offered there only works for headers but not for the header of an panel.
Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Update: Following my actual source code which isn't working:
<RadzenPanel AllowCollapse="true" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" JustifyContent="JustifyContent.Start" Gap="1px" Style="width: stretch; background-color:orange">
            <RadzenColumn >
                <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" JustifyContent="JustifyContent.Start">
                    <RadzenText>This to the left</RadzenText>
                </RadzenStack>
            </RadzenColumn>
            <RadzenColumn>
                <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Horizontal" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center" JustifyContent="JustifyContent.End">
                    <RadzenText>This to the right</RadzenText>
                </RadzenStack>
            </RadzenColumn>
        </RadzenRow>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ChildContent>
        <RadzenText>Content</RadzenText>
    </ChildContent>
</RadzenPanel>


You should post your code, ideally a "Minimal, Reproducible Example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
